# How does the "Any" descriptor work in Legend?

Tags: legend

In the recently released 1.0 version of Legend, is the Elemental Pony racial track lists the Combat Offensive Modifier as "Any".  Does this mean that I may select any ability score other than the Combat Defensive Modifier as the KOM, or does it mean I have to use my class KOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Legend* 1.0, “Any” does not appear for Key Ability Modifiers. These instances have been replaced with “Varies,” and the class or track in question dictates how that is determined (e.g. Sage lets you choose any you like, Rogue bases them on which tracks you select, and so on).

In the case of the Elemental Pony track, which has not been updated to 1.0, it is a Racial Track. That means it is a kind of combination race-class-track: your class is effectively “Elemental Pony” and you may choose your KOM freely from the five remaining ability scores (you cannot usually choose Con because it is your KDM, but if a track changes your KDM then it could become available).

As part of the work for the *Legend* monster guide, the various monstrous bonus content material is going to be updated to the 1.0 ruleset. I expect to see that “Any” changed to “Varies” and have the class explicitly state how that works – the way Sage does now.

In 1.0, “Any” is used for racial Bonus Feat lists, where it means exactly what it says on the tin. Races with “Any” racial bonus feat cannot ignore level requirements on their racial feat, the way that races with explicit lists can.